# CSS: text-align-last doesnt work in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

text-align-last is supposed to work in all modern browsers. Im using Chrome 38 and this css property doesn't seem to work - in Deverloper Tools, it strikes out this line.

Any ideas why it would happen? Maybe a Chrome 38 bug? I've found out that it was some kind of an issue in past version of Chrome.

[October 30, 2016 Edit: I'm pretty late with this, but if anyone still finds this answer, text-align-last is supported since Chrome 47, released in December 2015]

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76173

Comment: So it was never actually implemented before?

Comment: seems so, unfortunately.

Comment: The bug is marked as RESOLVED FIXED, but there does not seem to be any information about an actual fix having been implemented. MDN info says that there is support from Chrome 35 but links to this bug. And what I see in dev tools in Chrome 38 is that the declaration is struck-out but a tooltip text says that the property *value* is invalid. This is rather puzzling, but the bottom line seems to be that the feature is not supported.

Comment: Seems that the feature isn't supported in Chrome yet. But you can test with it when you enable 'Experimental Web Platform Features' via chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Comment: @vicente I have a client's website using this feature and it works only in firefox so far (and IE too!!), so that's why it was important to me. Any idea when we gonna get a better update for chrome with this feature and others?

Answer (score 2):

It has not been implemented in Chrome. There is a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76173) set to RESOLVED FIXED, but  there does not seem to be any information about an actual fix having been implemented. [MDN info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) says that there is support from Chrome 35 but links to this bug.

In dev tools in Chrome 38 the declaration is struck-out but a tooltip text says that the property *value* is invalid. In Chrome 40 this has been fixed: the tooltip says that the property *name* is invalid (meaning that it is not recognized/supported by the browser). Enabling “Experimental Web Platform Features” does not seem to help. So the property remains unimplemented.

Edit: As noted in the question now, Chrome supports the feature from version 47, and browser support is good (though not perfect) otherwise, too, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last

Answer (score -2):

Baseline positioning varies in browsers. That is why text-align-last in Chrome is behaving different. Explained here with possible fix

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/08/13/one-weird-trick-to-baseline-align-text

HTML

```
<div>
  <span class="letter">T</span>
  <span class="strut"></span>
<div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid;
}
.letter {
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 0px;
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
}
.strut {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Summary

1. Inline images use the bottom edge of the image as the baseline

2. So add an empty inline-block strut to the div to position the baseline for the entire line.

Comment: Maybe you could give a brief summary of the fix (in case the blog is no longer available in the future)

Comment: @digiron I think you got a bit confused. I am talking here about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last

Comment: This is about an entirely different issue, vertical alignment of text. The question is about horizontal alignment of last line of a block.