# Text align justify and last line center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

As you can see the text is justify but the last line is centered. I tried with this css approach but it doesn't center the last line. At least not in chrome:

```
p {
text-align: justify;  
-moz-text-align-last: right; /* Code for Firefox */
text-align-last: center;
}
```

Here it says it should work, but it doesn't: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-align-last.asp

Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787408/css-text-align-last-doesnt-work-in-chrome

Comment: The problem has disappeared, as Chrome support exists from version 47.

Answer (score 8):

Change `right` to `center`:

```
p {
    text-align: justify;  
    -moz-text-align-last: center; /* Code for Firefox */
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have it with center. I edited the question. Also even with right it doesn't put it in the right.

Comment: Not yet supported for webkit browsers other than firefox..see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last#Browser_compatibility